# Certain element sum from array

Tags: c++, arrays

new to C++ and in need of help with an array. Looking at the code below, you can see I have an array of 20 undefined elements. My queastion is how do I sum up elements from a[5] to a[14]. Only these elements. (Including them ofc)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int a[20];
    int summa;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        a[i] = rand()%6 + 5;
        cout << a[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to know how to use a `for`, so just change the range it operates on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use your knowledge of a for loop to add those values to your `summa` variable (which you did not initialize):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int a[20];
    // set this to 0 or your answer will be erroneous
    int summa = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        a[i] = rand()%6 + 5;
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    // Now sum the values you want
    for (int i = 5; i < 15; i++) {
        summa += a[i];
    }
    cout << "Sum from 5 to 14: " << summa << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate the whole array with a for loop - you can specify the indices you want. Then you can define an int sum that's set to 0 outside the loop, and add the value of a[i] to it for each value in your range.

```
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 4; i < 15; i++) {
       sum += a[i];
    }
    cout << sum << "\n";
```

Comment: I do it, because I need it to run and show the full array before suming everything up. Does it change anything?

Comment: You could either:
*  run through the entire loop (like your code does now) and then perform a second loop the sum up the values.
* have `a[i] = rand()%6 + 5;` before summing up the values in the same loop